# WebStorm can't find browser when hitting 'Run'

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have occurred an odd issue in WebStorm.

Every time I try to "run" a HTML document I get the error:

> Windows cannot find 'browser'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again. "

[image: Image of error]

I don't have Chrome installed and would like to use Edge as my default browser.

Now the odd thing is if I use the little Edge Browser icon to the top right on the HTML page, everything works fine:

[image: image of the badly described icon I am talking about] .

Trying to make it work I removed all other browsers from WebStorm, leaving only Edge, but it didn't change a thing (also I have tried all 3 options from the "Default Browser" drop down list:

[image: see image]

Edge is set as my default browser in Windows.

I'm eager to hear your ideas on what I have missed! :D

Comment: 1) Show how your "Run" looks like (the actual Run/Debug Configuration for that). It may still be using the old entry. 2) Looking at your last screenshot, the `browser` is associated with the Chrome family (`Yandex` entry).  AFAIK JS Debugging will work in Chrome based browser only .. and your `Edge` entry is "Internet Explorer" family. therefore I suggest manually creating a custom entry for the new Chromium-based Edge browser using Chrome family.

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, you are right. Changing Edge to the Chrome family made it work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript debugging can be performed using Chrome and other browsers of the Chrome family only, so opening Chrome when using run/debug configuration is expected.

This should work for Edge in principle (as new Edge is Chromium-based), fixing [WEB-45326](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-45326) should take care of this.
For now, I'd suggest setting up **Edge** as a new custom browser in **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers**:

- press **+** to add a new browser
- use *Chrome* as a **Family**, specify a full path to browser executable as **Path**, enter a name

Browser will be available with Chrome icon in run configuration dropdown

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your paths are not set to an actual folder path. For MacOS, the path to a browser like Chrome Canary looks something like this.

[image]